# Select second tab from ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

In my app delegate I load a view controller on top of my tabbar. This controller had three buttons on it, one to navigate to each tab. When the second button is pressed, I want to dismiss the view controller and go to the second tab. But this doesn't seem to work the normal way.

My AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    //-- Insert a delay of 5 seconds before the splash screen disappears
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];        

    // Set the tab bar controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    // Set StartView to load first
    StartViewController *startViewController = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartView" bundle: nil];
    [window addSubview: [startViewController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:startViewController animated:NO];
    [startViewController release];

    return YES;
}
```

And here is my current IBAction, which doesn't seem to work:

```
 - (IBAction) toSecondView:(id)sender
    {
    // Show status bar
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    [(UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController setSelectedIndex:1];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

I tried these too, without success:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

and

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Can anyone help me out and explain me what I'm missing?

Comment: it's happend because of ,you have added viewcontroller onto the window as subView and then presenting that viewController on tabBarController

Answer (score 0):

This happend because a below of reason.

You have added ViewController Onto the Window As a subView, no need to add SubView  because you are already presenting that ViewController as ModalViewController.

Please Try as below.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{    
//-- Insert a delay of 5 seconds before the splash screen disappears
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];        

// Set the tab bar controller as the window's root view controller and display.
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

// Set StartView to load first
StartViewController *startViewController = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartView" bundle: nil];
//[window addSubview: [startViewController view]]; no need to add subView here
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:startViewController animated:NO];
[startViewController release];
return YES;
```

}

```
-(IBAction) toSecondView:(id)sender
{
// Show status bar
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
//create delegate's class object for accessing tabBarController
 AppDelegate* delegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 //instead of [(UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController setSelectedIndex:1];
 //delegate.tabBarController your tabBarControler at which you have added viewController
[delegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

}